# Закрытие окна терминала после запуска программы

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, sh

Есть необходимость запускать программу (Feed The Beast Launcher) с предварительным выбором, так сказать, режима запуска. Пишу `sh-скрипт` такого плана:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
FTBDir="Путь"
MMWPDir="Путь"
JarLaunchDir="$HOME/Programs"
NameLaunch="FTB_Launcher.jar"
echo "Режим запуска:"
echo "1.Обычный"
echo "2.Сброс клиента"
cd $JarLaunchDir
read test
java -jar ./$NameLaunch&
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы после запуска программы терминал закрывался. Но  начинает выводиться лог работы самого лаунчера в терминал, соответственно всё, что после строки запуска, не выполняется, потому закрыть терминал не удаётся.

Предполагаю, что нужно как-то запускать в отдельном потоке, но как это сделать не понимаю.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247721/on-writing-a-linux-shell-script-to-safely-detach-programs-from-a-terminal ; Либо использовать `screen` ; Либо `supervisor` ; Либо написать init-скрипт.

Comment: `программа параметры & exit`

Comment: Может проще и удобнее сделать ярлык с несколькими вариантами запуска, как это сделано например в `/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop`?

Comment: @sercxjo, Может и проще, но не хочется плодить ярлыки в боковой панельке. По сути запускать я буду каждый раз в разных режимах, Для того и делаю сие гемор.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, всё оказалось не так просто, но просто

Answer (score 1):

Благодаря ссылке предоставленной [nobody](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199545/nobody) и методу тыка, решение получилось таким:

Нужно изменить `java -jar ./$NameLaunch` на следущее:

```
nohup java -jar ./$NameLaunch & sleep 0.01
exit
```

То есть 2 тонкости:

1. Обязательно должно быть `sleep` со значением больше 0
2. exit должно быть отдельно а не через `&`

Comment: Как-то ненаучно. Зачем `sleep`?

Comment: @Roman, Зачем, я так и не понял правда. Но в той же [теме](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247721/on-writing-a-linux-shell-script-to-safely-detach-programs-from-a-terminal/37134825#37134825)  было вроде описано почему так. Не вдавался в подробности, только проверил на практике что да, без sleep не фурчит

Comment: @BwehaaFox не, stackoverflow должен быть научным

Comment: А пробовали `disown` вместо `sleep`? Да ещё с перенаправлением ввода-вывода в `/dev/null`?